# ImportError: No module named 'pip'

Tags: ubuntu, pip

Сломался pip, возможно после очередного обновления пакетов.

```
root@host:/usr/local/bin# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

root@host:/usr/local/bin# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

root@host:/usr/local/bin# python -V
Python 2.7.6


root@host:/usr/local/bin# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin*
```

Была также установленная через apt-get версия, удалил её, проблема осталась.

Пробовал [установить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919613/2790048):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1488k  100 1488k    0     0  1184k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1184k
The directory '/home/n.volynkin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/n.volynkin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
/tmp/tmptqUbcI/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
/tmp/tmptqUbcI/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

> directory '/home/n.volynkin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user

Проверил, все принадлежат мне.

Про SNI вообще не понимаю, в чём ошибка.

Вопрос: как починить установку или хотя бы как целиком удалить уже установленный (и сломанный) pip? Откуда вообще взялся pip в /usr/local/bin/pip?

Comment: @iksuy нее, php не ломался )

Comment: Какова первая строчка в файле /usr/local/bin/pip?

Comment: Что-то не нравится мне, что python у вас второй, а pip использует библиотеки третьего...

Comment: @PavelMayorov внезапно, pip2 работает, а pip3 выдаёт тот же результат. Первая строчка: `#!/usr/bin/python3.4`

Comment: Тогда надо делать `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.4`

Comment: @PavelMayorov о, вроде сработало. Первая строка осталась той же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46410/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, откатил, лажанул :)

Comment: 1. `/usr/local/bin/pip` так именно и «взялся»: `$ curl ... | sudo ...`. удалять его придётся точно так же — «ручками». 2. рекомендую обновить пакеты (`$ sudo apt-get update; sudo atp-get upgrade`) и установить pip**3**: `$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score -1):

Переустановите Python на более новую версию.  Далее:

1. Нажмите на Customize Installation,
2. Выберите там пункт - Install for all users,
3. И также выберите пункт Add pip to Path. И устанавливаете Python.

Если до-сих пор не работает, напишите:

```
Python -m pip install (тут название модуля).
```

Comment: Где вы нашли "Customize Installation" в линуксе?